# Good Book/Training material to learn multithreading in C/C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am just a starter at using threads in my code. I use Boost threads usually.

But I don't think I have mastered this field yet.

I am looking for learning material specifically for advanced parallel programming. Could anybody suggest something.

Comment: Continue using boost. It is the best, probably easiest and robust, option you have at present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an early access edition of C++ Concurrency in Action available at http://www.manning.com/williams/ He's very knowledgeable on the subject and AFAIK he's the author of boost threads and has also just released a version of std::thread conforming to the new c++0x standard. 
I'm also reading Concurrent Programming on Windows by Joe Duffy which is a pretty good read so far: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/books/winconc/winconc_book_resources.html

Update:
Also, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415994/boost-thread-tutorials/3951227#3951227

Comment: I second C++ Concurrency in Action. Good book.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should continue using Boosts threads, they will be usable on different OS's. 
 I haven't read any good books on multithreading, but you could take a pick (and preview) some at [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+multithreading&btnG=S%C3%B6k+i+b%C3%B6cker&tbs=bks:1&tbo=1&hl=sv&qscrl=1).